# How to make checkboxes wrap nicely?

Tags: html, css

I am making a small form where the user can choose different food categories but there are too many so I wanted to make it scrollable but right now the options have odd breakpoints (see picture link below) does anyone know how I can fix this easily with css?

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwADS.png)

This is the html of my form:

```css
.favForm-categories{
 overflow: scroll;
 overflow-x: inherit;
 height: 20rem;
}

.fav-choice {
 line-height: 3.3rem;
 margin: .1rem;
 color: white;
 padding: .5rem;
 width: fit-content;
 border: solid .1rem white;
 border-radius: var(--borderRadiusButton);
 background-color: var(--color2);
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
 appearance: none;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: .5rem;
 color: white;
 width: 1rem;
 height: 1rem;
 border: .3rem solid white;
 border-radius: var(--borderRadiusButton);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
 background-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<section class="favForm">
  <h3 class="small-title">Choose your favourite categories</h3>
  <form class="favForm-options" action="index.php?pages=home" method="POST">
    <div class="favForm-categories">
      <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="add_category">
      <?php
        foreach ($category as $cat) {
          echo('<label class="fav-choice" for="'.$cat->RecipeCategory.'"><input class="checkbox-hide" type="checkbox" id="'.$cat->RecipeCategory.'" name="fav_category[]" value="'.$cat->RecipeCategory.'">'.$cat->RecipeCategory.'</label>');
        }
      ?>
    </div>
    <input class="green-button" type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: To `.fav-choice` add `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: You can self-answer to share how to fix it !